# Pythonic way of comparing all adjacent values in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3,],
     [4, 5, 6, 7,],
     [8, 9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

For some `a[i][j]` is there way to get the 8 values around around it without having to specify `a[i-1][j-1], a[i][j-1], ... , a[i+1][j+1]`? If not is there at least a way to handle cases on the edge without having to check if I'm on the edge or not?

Comment: Can you be a bit elaborate . about what comparison you want to perform? a bit more problem description would be nice.

Comment: You'll need to treat the corners different also.

Comment: @Gouri I don't specifically want to compare but just to be able to get all 8 values in another list would be fine.

Comment: Python lists only or can you use other libraries?

Comment: For my specific case I can only use python lists but I'm curious to see if there are solutions using other libraries if I ever run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: Related: [Comparing value with neighbor elements in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214416/comparing-value-with-neighbor-elements-in-numpy)

Comment: A little difficult picking a possible duplicate but maybe: [Python - comparing elements of list with 'neighbour' elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529838/python-comparing-elements-of-list-with-neighbour-elements)

Comment: Searching with with combinations of `python compare neighbors lists array  matrix` produce interesting results.  There are results in Code Review also.

Comment: Do you want just the eight neighbors or do you want all nine values.

Comment: @vnal, I have added a solution. Take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `n` is the number of rows, and `m` is the number of columns.

First, when will i and j be valid? If `0 <= i < n` and `0 <= j < m`, it's valid.

```py
#Code to check if i and j are valid
def is_valid(i, j, n, m):
    if 0 <= i < n and 0 <= j < m:
        return True

    return False
```

To get adjacent values, you have to find all possible combinations where you can do nothing, add 1, or subtract 1 to both `i` and `j`. But if you do nothing to both `i` and `j`, it will give you the current element, which we don't want.

```py
#Code to get the adjacent values
def get_adjacent(a, i, j, n, m):
    l = []

    for x in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for y in [-1, 0, 1]:
            if not (x == y == 0) and is_valid(i+x, j+y, n, m):
                l.append(a[i+x][j+y])

    return l
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a very clean way to do it, but using slices seems to be more pythonic than accessing individual elements. Also, you only need to check for top and bottom edges using this method.

```
def foo(a):
    for r_i in range(len(a)):
        for i in range(len(a[0])):
            values = []
            if r_i > 0:
                values.extend(a[r_i - 1][max(0, i - 1):i + 2])
            values.extend(a[r_i][max(0, i - 1):i + 2])
            if r_i < len(a) - 1:
                values.extend(a[r_i + 1][max(0, i - 1):i + 2])
            print(values)  # do stuff with `values`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the below solution that takes care of the edge cases. Not sure if there is a more pythonic way.

```
a = [[0, 1, 2, 3,],
     [4, 5, 6, 7,],
     [8, 9, 10, 11],
     [12, 13, 14, 15]]

def print_edge_values(outer_idx, outer_len, inner_idx, inner_len):
    print("sorrounding values: "),
    for i in range(max(0, outer_idx-1), min(outer_idx+2, outer_len)):
        for j  in range(max(0, inner_idx-1), min(inner_idx+2, inner_len)):
            if((i,j) != (outer_idx, inner_idx)):
                print((i, j), "=", a[i][j], " "),
    print("")


for idx, item in enumerate(a):
    print(idx,":", item)
    for idx2, i in enumerate(item):
        print("value(%d, %d)= %d" % (idx, idx2, a[idx][idx2]))
        print_edge_values(idx, len(a), idx2, len(item))
```